# Getting Axios data with an Array in React Typescript

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, react-hooks

This is the Response from my Server:
[image]

Im trying fetch data from Array. How can i do that please?

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:5001/api/products',
  timeout: 15000,
});

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data.value;

const requests = {
  get: (url: string) => instance.get(url).then(responseBody)
};

const Post = {
  getPosts: (): Promise<Article[]> => requests.get('/article'),
}

useEffect(() => {
  Post.getPosts()
    .then((data) => {
      setArticle(data);

    });
  return () => {};
}, []);
```

Comment: After setting state you can now simply map the array into tsx elements.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rcerrejon/04677293787cf7bdaca7c44bad87bb8d check this code example it might help you

Comment: `instance.get<Article[]>(url).then(r=>r.data)` should give you back a `Promise<Article[]>`